# "No entanto " leva vírgula antes e depois quando ao meio de uma frase?

Tags: etimologia, sintaxe, significado-em-contexto, definição, frases

"No entanto" leva vírgula antes e depois quando no meio de uma frase?

Por exemplo, em:

> Gosto de futebol, no entanto, vejo pouco.
> Gosto de futebol, no entanto vejo pouco.
> "O filho caiu, no entanto, esta bem".
> "O filho caiu, no entanto esta bem."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Introdução

Na língua portuguesa, é comum utilizarmos um termo ou uma locução para conectar orações. Chamamos esse termo/locução de conjunção.

As conjunções são dividas em *coordenativas* e *subordinativas*. A locução *no entanto* é classificada como uma conjunção coordenada sindética pelo fato de ela ligar duas orações distintas, independentes.

> *Eu gosto de futebol*, no entanto *não assisti ao jogo*.

Observe que a frase *Eu gosto de futebol* não depende da oração *não assisti ao jogo* e vice-versa. Ambas podem ser pronunciadas (ou escritas) de formas independente e serão entendidas do mesmo jeito.

#### Uso da vírgula

O uso da vírgula é obrigatório antes das conjunções adversativas (*mas*, *no entanto*, *toda via*, *entretanto* etc); no entanto, após a conjunção, é facultativa — em regra.

Segue abaixo as opções possíveis.

> Gosto de futebol, no entanto, vejo pouco jogos.
>   Gosto de futebol; no entanto, vejo pouco jogos.
>   Gosto de futebol, no entanto vejo pouco jogos.
>   Gosto de futebol; vejo, no entanto, poucos jogos.
>   Gosto de futebol; vejo poucos jogos, no entanto.

Nas duas últimas frases, a locução *no entanto* está deslocada (ela deveria aparecer antes do verbo *vejo*), neste caso — como ela não está na posição que deveria — a segunda vírgula passa a ser obrigatória.

> **Atenção!** A vírgula após a conjunção *mas* é proibida.

Comment: ver na televisão, ou assistir, né?

Comment: No entanto seguindo de ; também é valido?

Comment: First GOLD Question :)

Comment: Não é possível utilizar ponto e vírgula após "no entanto".